# C++ template class - inheritance calling wrong function

Tags: c++, function, templates, inheritance, containers

I want to stop calling base "int" function. I would like to call inherited with "double"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, size_t N>
class A {
public:

};

template<size_t N>
class A<int, N> {
public:
void push(const int& val)             
 {
    cout << val << endl;
 }
};

template<size_t N>
class A<double, N>
: public A<int, N>
{
public:

};


int main() {
A<double, 8> r;
r.push(5.7);
return 0;
}
```

Warning gives me implicit conversion from double to int. How can I prevent calling function with int?

Edit:
I would like to use specialization and treat ints, doubles and floats as NUMBERS during sorting or processing, and treating string differently. Thats why I want to use specialization. I am trying to inherit doubles and floats because of the same algorithm for numbers, I am just trying to change the data type after inheriting and keep another functionality like "push" still available to use. Basically saving 5k lines combined.

Comment: There's no function taking a `double` in your code.

Comment: So there's no way to "rewrite it" with just derivation? And using double instead of int?

Comment: Rewrite it? Nothing is rewritten when you inherit. The members of the base are still *the same* members of the base.

Comment: Why are you using derivation here? Or specialization? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why not write `void push(const T& val)` in primary template, and get rid of specializations?

Comment: I have around 2k lines. T is meant for strings, objects. And specialization for int double and float (for sorting algorithms), I am trying to write it inside "int" and derive from it to double and float

Comment: Just to save space, with inheriting

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to treat `std::string`s and `int`s differently?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it above, because of sorting algorithms I want to process the data differently

Comment: Ok, then you might need specialization. Why do you want inheritance with `int` and `double` though? And this time, write it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Editted the post

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand that you need different versions of `push` depending on `T`.

You can use meta-programming for this.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, size_t N, typename = void>
class A {
  public:
    void push(const T& value) {
      // General version
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
class A<T, N, std::enable_if_t<
                   std::is_intergral<T>::value ||
                   std::is_floating_point<T>::value>>> {
  public:
    void push(const T& value) {
        // Integral & floating point version
    }
};
```

Comment: `is_numeric` is not a standard trait. You probably meant `is_arithmetic` (which coincidentally already covers floating point types).

Comment: I meant to write `std::is_integral`, I edited the answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer! I am  just asking... Would there be another way without using tools from std?

Comment: Thanks for answers guys :)